# Powershell loop files into program, if exit code is not equal to 0 move the file

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement, foreach

I have a program that returns an exit code of 1 if a text file is empty or if it has a header record and no other contents.

I'm trying to have powershell loop the contents of a folder (text files) into the program, and if the program returns an exit code not equal to 0, move the file to another location. Here's what I have so far:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -name C:\SourceFolder
$files | ForEach-Object {C:\TestProgram.cmd $_ } | ForEach-Object { if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {Move-Item $_.FullName C:\DestFolder} }
```

It's looping through the source folder fine and running the test program against it (dummy script returning an exit code of 1), and it looks like it's running the if statement correctly, but the $_.FullName after the Move-Item has lost its relationship with the original object (the file read in). It's now just the exit code at this point. I'm probably way off, is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Totally possible, just don't split up your ForEach loops like you are. Your array of files are being fed into the first ForEach loop, but that ForEach loop doesn't actually pass anything down the pipeline, so the next ForEach loop has no input at all. Just combine the two of them:

```
$files | ForEach-Object {
    C:\TestProgram.cmd $_ 
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {Move-Item $_.FullName C:\DestFolder} 
}
```

Comment: If it's running the if statement, then an item was produced. In all likelihood the item is the standard output of the command as an array of strings.